# Loggin data from SQL to Redis in Laravel

Tags: laravel, performance, logging, redis, audit

I'm doing an application in Laravel that contains several connections to different databases, in which each one reads a service audit table. The application is to visualize logs of different applications.

To improve the reading speed, could be possible download every X minutes all data from different bases to a local base in Redis and read the queries directly from it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via scheduled tasks:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands

This will allow you to run an Artisan Command

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan

In this command you can get the data from your DB and save it to your Redis table

To access mulitple Databases follow the details here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#read-and-write-connections

And to setup redis here is the docs

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redis

All that you will need to do is track what you have transfered.

Get what you have not transferred and then save that data to the Redis table